# Why oci_num_rows always return 0 value?

Tags: php, oracle

I have the code of this problem:

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';

    if (oci_execute ( $stmt )) {
        //Execute cursor
        oci_execute($result);  //Or you can return the cursor.
    }


    $count=oci_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    if ($count != 1)
    {
    echo $count;
    echo "No record";
    }
    else
    {

   while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)){
   <tr>
   <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[0]; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[1]; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[2]; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[3]; ?></div></td>
   <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[4]; ?></div></td>
    <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[5]; ?></div></td>
     <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[6]; ?></div></td>
     <td><div align="center" class="style4"><?php echo $objResult[7]; ?></div></td>

     <td><div align="center" class="style4"><a href="updateInsForm.php?insid=<?php echo $objResult[0]; ?>">EDIT</a></div></td>
     <td><div align="center" class="style4"><a href="deleteInsForm.php?insid=<?php echo $objResult[0]; ?>">DELETE</div></td>

    <?php 
   }
   }


   oci_close($objConnect);
 ?>
```

the problem is when i try to enter correct id and password, it return the row as 0..why?

Comment: Where is your $stmt defined? What is the value of it?

Comment: What `oci_execute ( $stmt )`  does?

Comment: ohh i skip the code for the query.. its is on $result

Comment: Have you checked out the manual of oci* http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php your code does not match the examples of fetching results. see Example #5  `$stmt=oci_parse($conn, $sql); oci_execute($stmt); $count=oci_num_rows($stmt);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that num_rows function return the number of items that were fetched, not the result executed. from the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php

Note:
This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT statements this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```php
<?php
    include 'connection.php';

    if (oci_execute($stmt)) {
        // Execute cursor
        $result = $stmt; // Assign the cursor to $result
    }

    $count = oci_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    if ($count != 1) {
        echo "No record";
    } else {
        while ($objResult = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[0] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[1] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[2] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[3] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[4] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[5] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[6] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'>" . $objResult[7] . "</div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'><a href='updateInsForm.php?insid=" . $objResult[0] . "'>EDIT</a></div></td>";
            echo "<td><div align='center' class='style4'><a href='deleteInsForm.php?insid=" . $objResult[0] . "'>DELETE</a></div></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    oci_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Assign the executed cursor `$stmt` to `$result` instead of executing it again with `oci_execute($result)`. Corrected the opening and closing PHP tags to wrap the HTML code within the while loop. Added appropriate echo statements to output the HTML table rows and columns.Properly formatted the href attributes for the "EDIT" and "DELETE" links.